# Gridfs cannot find file in different buckets

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I have added a file into the collection `my_collections`.

I am not able check if the file was saved.

With the default bucket (`fs.chunk` and `fs.files`) the code below works properly

```
db.my_collection.files.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("50e03d29edfdc00d34000001"), "filename" : "hd.txt", "contentType" : "plain/text", "length" : 85, "chunkSize" : 1024, "uploadDate" : ISODate("2014-10-29T06:57:42.375Z"), "aliases" : null, "metadata" : {  }, "md5" : "dc20cdc19005d04b8c36a889128170a8" }
```

Code:

```
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'testgridfs');
conn.once('open', function () {
var gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);


  var options =  {
    _id: '50e03d29edfdc00d34000001', // a MongoDb ObjectId
    filename: 'hd.txt', // a filename
    mode: 'w',
    chunkSize: 1024,
    content_type: 'plain/text',
    root: 'my_collection',//<<<<< **if i comment it ,default collection is taken and codee works fine**
    metadata: {}
  }



  // write (this works in both default and custom bucket case)
  // var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream(options);
  // fs.createReadStream('/home/pop/Downloads/hd.txt').pipe(writestream);


  //chk exits or not
  gfs.exist(options  , function (err, found) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
      found ? console.log('File exists') : console.log('File does not exist');
    });  
})
```

The file is shown in `db.my_collection.files` but code shows `File does not exist`

The same code works if the root option is removed.

I want to use multiple buckets as documented in [the GridFS reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/gridfs/#gridfs-reference).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in version.
the code on github is latest 0.5.3
while on npm it is 0.5.1..

so i have downloaded manually from github and everything works fine.
https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream